# Lucene exception NoSuchMethodError with version 6.4.0

Tags: java, lucene, text-analysis

I am relatively new to Lucene and playing with the latest version 6.4.0.

I have written a cutom analyzer class for doing synonyms,

```
public class MySynonymAnalyzer extends Analyzer {

@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
    Tokenizer source = new ClassicTokenizer();
    TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter(source);
    filter = new LowerCaseFilter(filter);
    filter = new SynonymGraphFilter(filter, getSynonymsMap(), false);
    filter = new FlattenGraphFilter(filter);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
}

private SynonymMap getSynonymsMap() {
    try {
        SynonymMap.Builder builder = new SynonymMap.Builder(true);
        builder.add(new CharsRef("work"), new CharsRef("labor"), true);
        builder.add(new CharsRef("work"), new CharsRef("effort"), true);
        SynonymMap mySynonymMap = builder.build();
        return mySynonymMap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the line where I call `getSynonymsMap()`, I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.lucene.util.UnicodeUtil.UTF16toUTF8WithHash([CIILorg/apache/lucene/util/BytesRef;)I
>       at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymMap$Builder.add(SynonymMap.java:192)
>       at org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.SynonymMap$Builder.add(SynonymMap.java:239)
>       at m2_lab4.MySynonymAnalyzer.getSynonymsMap(MySynonymAnalyzer.java:37)
>       at m2_lab4.MySynonymAnalyzer.createComponents(MySynonymAnalyzer.java:28)
>       at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:162)
>       at org.apache.lucene.document.Field.tokenStream(Field.java:568)

Version 6.4.0 doesn't seem to have method `UTF16toUTF8WithHash` in class `UnicodeUtil`. I am using everything from lucene 6.4.0 and there doesn't seem to be any old versioned jar in my classpath. This is how my maven dependendies look like:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <lucene.version>6.4.0</lucene.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-facet</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.spatial4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>spatial4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea what's going on? I am specially puzzled by the `[CIILorg/apache/lucene/util/BytesRef` text inside the exception description.

Comment: `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>***3.6.2***</version>
    </dependency>`

Comment: @femtoRgon But for lucene.analyzers, 3.6.2 seems to be the latest. Isn't it?

Comment: @femtoRgon Thanks man. I removed that lucene-analyzers-3.6.2 dependency, and I already had the analyzers-common dependency with the latest 6.4.0 version. Removing the old one worked like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, noticed you already had analyzers-common after commenting, there. Glad that resolved it for you.